# Displaying some kind of data in fullcalendar with errors?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using  full calendar to aggregate and show events added via CMS.
I have a problem with "0" before every entry and not parsing –

You can see it here in action:

http://www.florystyka.com/kalendarium

It's in polish language.

For example date 12.04.2016 (12th of April) looks like:

```
<div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">0</span> <span class="fc-title">Komunia święta &amp;#8211; od wianuszka do dekoracji kościoła</span></div>
```

I can see that fc-time is 0, maybe this is bad configuration of plugin?

Here is the JS code:

```
<script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
                nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00', 
                //allDay:false,
                eventSources: [

                    {
                        events: [{"start":"2016-10-01","title":"Florysta","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kursy\/florysta","color":"#6390BE","description":""},{"start":"2016-10-01","title":"Florysta","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kursy\/florysta","color":"#6390BE","description":""},{"start":"2016-10-08","title":"Mistrz florystyki","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kursy\/mistrz-florystyki-kurs","color":"#6390BE","description":""},{"start":"2016-10-08","title":"Mistrz florystyki","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kursy\/mistrz-florystyki-kurs","color":"#6390BE","description":""}]                         
                    },
                    {
                        events: [{"start":"2016-05-16","end":"2016-05-19T23:59:00","title":"Pierwsze kroki z florystyk\u0105","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/warsztaty\/pierwsze-kroki-z-florystyka","color":"#acd342","description":""},{"start":"2016-04-19","end":"2016-04-21T23:59:00","title":"Bukiety na ka\u017cd\u0105 okazj\u0119-klasyka i nowoczesno\u015b\u0107","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/warsztaty\/bukiety-na-kazda-okazje","color":"#acd342","description":""},{"start":"2016-06-13","end":"2016-06-16T23:59:00","title":"\u015alub marze\u0144 &#8211; ameryka\u0144skie inspiracje","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/warsztaty\/amerykanski-slub","color":"#acd342","description":""},{"start":"2016-05-31","end":"2016-06-02T23:59:00","title":"Wi\u0105zanki \u015blubne &#8211; klasyka i nowoczesno\u015b\u0107","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/warsztaty\/nowoczesne-wiazanki-slubne","color":"#acd342","description":""},{"start":"2016-04-12","end":"2016-04-14T23:59:00","title":"Komunia \u015bwi\u0119ta &#8211; od wianuszka do dekoracji ko\u015bcio\u0142a","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/warsztaty\/pierwsza-komunia","color":"#acd342","description":""},{"start":"2016-08-09","end":"2016-08-11T23:59:00","title":"Magia r\u00f3\u017c","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/warsztaty\/magia-roz","color":"#acd342","description":""},{"start":"2016-08-23","end":"2016-08-25T23:59:00","title":"Florystyka \u017ca\u0142obna","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/warsztaty\/7689-2","color":"#acd342","description":""},{"start":"2016-11-14","end":"2016-11-16T23:59:00","title":"Wianki i ozdoby adwentowe","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/warsztaty\/7698-2","color":"#acd342","description":""}]                          
                    },
                    {
                        events: [{"start":"2014-09-27","end":"2014-09-29","title":"Dyplom Florysty 2014, wystawa prac dyplomowych w Wilanowie","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/aktualnosci\/wystawa-prac-dyplomowych-florysta-2014","color":"#EA689C","description":""},{"start":"2015-11-14","title":"IPM 2013 Essen","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/aktualnosci\/ipm-2013-essen","color":"#EA689C","description":""}]                            
                    },
                    {
                        events: [{"start":"2016-07-11","end":"2016-07-16","title":"Podstawy Florystyki PF\/07\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/podstawy-florystyki-pf072016","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 1\/2"},{"start":"2016-07-18","end":"2016-07-23","title":"Podstawy Florystyki PF\/07\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/podstawy-florystyki-pf072016","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 2\/2"},{"start":"2016-06-20","end":"2016-06-23","title":"Wpis pr\u00f3bny","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/wpis-probny","color":"#EA689C","description":""},{"start":"2016-07-06","end":"2016-07-11","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 03\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-dzienny-fd-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Ostatni zjazd"},{"start":"2016-07-06","end":"2016-07-11","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-weekendowy-fw-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Ostatni zjazd"},{"start":"2015-10-03","end":"2015-10-05","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 1\/24"},{"start":"2015-10-10","end":"2015-10-12","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 2\/24"},{"start":"2015-10-17","end":"2015-10-19","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 3\/24"},{"start":"2015-11-14","end":"2015-11-16","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 4\/24"},{"start":"2015-11-21","end":"2015-11-23","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 5\/24"},{"start":"2015-12-05","end":"2015-12-07","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 6\/24"},{"start":"2015-12-12","end":"2015-12-14","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 7\/24"},{"start":"2016-01-09","end":"2016-01-11","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 8\/24"},{"start":"2016-01-16","end":"2016-01-18","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 9\/24"},{"start":"2016-02-06","end":"2016-02-08","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 10\/24"},{"start":"2016-03-12","end":"2016-03-14","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 11\/24"},{"start":"2016-03-19","end":"2016-03-21","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 12\/24"},{"start":"2016-04-09","end":"2016-04-11","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 13\/24"},{"start":"2016-04-23","end":"2016-04-25","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 14\/24"},{"start":"2016-05-07","end":"2016-05-09","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 15\/24"},{"start":"2016-05-14","end":"2016-05-16","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 16\/24"},{"start":"2016-06-04","end":"2016-06-06","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 17\/24"},{"start":"2016-06-11","end":"2016-06-13","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 18\/24"},{"start":"2016-06-18","end":"2016-06-20","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 19\/24"},{"start":"2016-07-02","end":"2016-07-04","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 20\/24"},{"start":"2016-08-06","end":"2016-08-08","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 21\/24"},{"start":"2016-08-13","end":"2016-08-15","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 22\/24"},{"start":"2016-08-18","end":"2016-08-22","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 23,24\/24  ostatni"},{"start":"2016-03-05","end":"2016-03-07","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 1\/24"},{"start":"2016-03-12","end":"2016-03-14","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 2\/24"},{"start":"2016-03-19","end":"2016-03-21","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 3\/24"},{"start":"2016-04-09","end":"2016-04-11","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 4\/24"},{"start":"2016-04-23","end":"2016-04-25","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 5\/24"},{"start":"2016-05-07","end":"2016-05-09","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 6\/24"},{"start":"2016-05-14","end":"2016-05-16","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 7\/24"},{"start":"2016-06-04","end":"2016-06-06","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 8\/24"},{"start":"2016-06-11","end":"2016-06-13","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 9\/24"},{"start":"2016-06-18","end":"2016-06-20","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 10\/24"},{"start":"2016-07-02","end":"2016-07-04","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 11\/24"},{"start":"2016-08-06","end":"2016-08-08","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 12\/24"},{"start":"2016-08-13","end":"2016-08-15","title":"Florysta weekendowy FW 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fw-032015-8","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 13\/24"},{"start":"2015-10-03","end":"2015-10-05","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 1\/12"},{"start":"2015-10-12","end":"2015-10-16","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 2\/12"},{"start":"2015-11-16","end":"2015-11-20","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 3\/12"},{"start":"2015-12-07","end":"2015-12-11","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 4\/12"},{"start":"2016-01-11","end":"2016-01-15","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 5\/12"},{"start":"2016-02-01","end":"2016-02-05","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 6\/12"},{"start":"2016-03-14","end":"2016-03-18","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 7\/12"},{"start":"2016-04-04","end":"2016-04-08","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 8\/12"},{"start":"2016-04-25","end":"2016-04-29","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 9\/12"},{"start":"2016-05-09","end":"2016-05-13","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 10\/12"},{"start":"2016-06-06","end":"2016-06-10","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 11\/12"},{"start":"2016-08-01","end":"2016-08-05","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 12\/12"},{"start":"2016-08-15","end":"2016-08-22","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 10\/2015","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-102015-4","color":"#6390BE","description":"Ostatni zjazd"},{"start":"2016-01-22","end":"2016-01-25","title":"Podstawy florystyki","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/podstawy-florystyki","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 1\/4"},{"start":"2016-01-29","end":"2016-02-01","title":"Podstawy florystyki","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/podstawy-florystyki","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 2\/4"},{"start":"2016-02-12","end":"2016-02-15","title":"Podstawy florystyki","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/podstawy-florystyki","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 3\/4"},{"start":"2016-02-26","end":"2016-02-29","title":"Podstawy florystyki","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/podstawy-florystyki","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 4\/4"},{"start":"2016-03-05","end":"2016-03-07","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 1\/12 "},{"start":"2016-03-14","end":"2016-03-18","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 2\/12"},{"start":"2016-04-04","end":"2016-04-08","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 3\/12"},{"start":"2016-04-25","end":"2016-04-29","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 4\/14"},{"start":"2016-05-09","end":"2016-05-13","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 5\/14"},{"start":"2016-06-06","end":"2016-06-10","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 6\/14"},{"start":"2016-08-01","end":"2016-08-05","title":"Florysta dzienny FD 03\/2016","url":"http:\/\/www.florystyka.com\/kalendarium\/florysta-fd-032015","color":"#6390BE","description":"Zjazd 7\/14"}]                           
                    }


                ],
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element.qtip({
                        content: event.description,
                    position: {
                        my: 'top center',
                        at: 'bottom center',
                    }






                    });
                }

            });

        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your event end values have a time component.  This makes the guessing logic decide that it is not an all day event so it shows the hour of the start, which is zero because the start dates have no time component.  You can resolve by making start and end consistent, either both have a time or neither has a time for any particular event.

Comment: thanks for answear :) will try in 15 minutes :)
I think it will works.
How to achieve parsing :
     &#8211 ?